# Deprecated password authentication with github warning

Tags: github, token, teamcity, deprecated

Hello community can you please help me out, not very knowledgeable in this area

I got an email from git saying that personal password is no longer gonna be supported and that team city was using it so I went into GitHub and generated a token and added to the VCS in the, after our next deploy I got an email from GitHub saying, you are still using the password dummy, so I asked our server guy to update TeamCity as we were several versions behind, so he did and we ran a deploy again today. I pay a visit to the VCS again and saw my Authentication method was set to Password/Token. I got no email from GIT this time saying I was dummy and "Developer Settings/Personal access tokens" mention TeamCity has used it but TeamCity keeps saying this ▼▼▼▼ any ideas ?? Thanks.

*git) https://github.com//xxxxxxxxxx is using deprecated password authentication with github.com and will soon stop working

Please consider switching to either personal access token or to SSH private key authentication.
Edit VCS root*

Answer (score 1):

Solution as mentioned in the error.
It is also [mentioned on TeamCity documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/github.html)

[image]

You may either use [SSH priv/pub keys as authentication or "Personal Access Token"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/git.html#Authentication+Settings).

I can tell by `git) https://github.com//xxxxxxxxxx` that you are currently using `HTTPS` instead of `SSH` to source your VCS, so the most similar solution is [GitHub Private Access Token (linked: how-to)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

Go to Setting > Developer Settings > Personal Access Token and click "Generate New".

If this is a private GitHub repo, you will need to tick the **"repo"** scope.

On your TeamCity VCS change the password to be the Personal Access Token you generated.

**Tip**: since you can not view the PAT after generating nor after using on the VCS, it is recommend to set the PAT as a root configuration variable, so you can call it on this VCS, build features, or other future use.